# There is no ListView in Additional Controls

Tags: vba

I tried to run VBA application on someone else's computer, but I get an error:
"Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine"

I checked all the references, and they seem ok. During research I found out that the object that is missing is ListView control. I checked if there is Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) checked in references - and there is. I tried to reinstall this library but it still didn't do any good.

I checked that there is no "Microsoft ListView Control, version 6.0" in Additional Controls, nor "Microsoft ImageList Control, version 6.0". Seems like the library isn't there, althought I can see the MSCOMCTL.OCX in C:\windows\system32\ with right last modification date and size.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: One suggestion: I never recommend using Listview Control in VBA as it cannot be freely distributed. It's not necessary that every one will have it. :)

Comment: It's business application for employees - they are obligated to install whatever we need, and we really do need listview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you could try to register `MSCOMCTL.OCX` file with `regsvr32`:

```
regsvr32 c:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

or for 64 bit systems

```
regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\mscomctl.ocx
```

Remember to open the command prompt in Administrator mode first.