# VBA Listview controls are missing - Windows7

Tags: vba, excel

I have the same problem as described on this post: [There is no ListView in Additional Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768483/there-is-no-listview-in-additional-controls) but the solutions which suggested there didn't helped me
I built a file with userforms with listview. I sent this file to user which have windows7, 64 bit, but when he opened the file he got the error message "couldn't load an object". i found out that the listview controls are missing. i've installed the  MSCOMCTL.OCX file through the command prompt and it shows that the installation was succeeded but the problem is still exist.. 
Please your help to find a way to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Does he have 64bit Office as well as Windows? If so, you can't.

Comment: Yes, he have office 64bit:( there is no way to solve the problem? @Rory

Comment: Not unless you can find a third-party version. Microsoft does not have a 64bit version of the common controls.

Comment: There is alternative control which exist in 64bit, and can be alternative for the listview?

Comment: Again, not unless you can find a third party version. I don't know of one.

Comment: i don't know how to find third party version.. do you know if i use the listbox has the same abilities and features as listview?

Comment: No it doesn't. There wouldn't be much point in having two identical controls.